# Solving this limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{x+1/x}}{(x+1/x)^x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{x+1/x}}{(x+1/x)^x}$$

I have tried a lot of things, like:

- transforming those terms to:
  $$\frac{e^{(x+1/x)\ln(x)}}{e^{x\ln(x+1/x)}}$$
- then I tried L'Hôpital's rule but it was just getting more complex
- I also made them one, like:
  $$e^{(x+1/x)\ln(x)-x\ln(x+1/x)}$$
- At last, I tried to "squeeze" them but I couldn't find the perfect function for that.

I hope that this is not a duplicate because I searched but I couldn't find a similar post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite the limit as
$$L = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{x^2 + 1}{x}}}{\left(\frac{x^2 + 1}{x}\right)^x} = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{2x^2 + 1}{x}}}{(x^2 + 1)^x} = \lim_{x \to +\infty} e^\ell,$$
where
$$\require{cancel}\ell = \frac{2x^2 + 1}x\ln x - x\ln(x^2 + 1) = \cancel{2x\ln x} + \frac1x\ln x - \cancel{2x\ln x} - x\ln\left(1 + \frac1{x^2}\right).$$
Since $\ell \to 0$ and $\exp(x)$ is continuous, we conclude that the limit is $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, appreciate it!

Comment: @George.K I'm happy I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the function as
$$
\left(\frac{x}{x+1/x}\right)^{\!x}x^{1/x}=
\left(\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}\right)^{\!x}x^{1/x}
$$
Now
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\log x=0
$$
so
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{1/x}=1
$$
and we just need to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}x\log\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}=
-\lim_{x\to\infty}x\log\frac{x^2+1}{x^2}=
-\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\log(1+t^2)}{t}=
-\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{t^2+o(t^2)}{t}=0
$$
so also
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}\right)^{\!x}=1
$$

Comment: I can't understand those last two equalities: $$
-\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\log(1+t^2)}{t}=
-\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{t^2+o(t^2)}{t}=0
$$ is $$o(t^2)$$ some function or you did something else?

Comment: @George.K That's customary notation when dealing with Taylor expansion; if you don't know it, the limit is easily computed with l'Hôpital, or by recalling that $\lim_{u\to0}\frac{1+u}{u}=1$ and so $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\log(1+t^2)}{t}=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\log(1+t^2)}{t^2}\cdot t=1\cdot0=0$

Comment: yeah, I didn't know that, but I will search about it and learn it. Thanks for the answer and the comment, I appreciate it!

Comment: Oh, I knew Taylor's series but I didn't know we could use this theorem to calculate limits. Now I see,thanks!